# Provide permission to Event object to Site Guest User

Tags: profile, permission-sets, guest-user

I want to give Create Permission for Activity-Event to site guest user. Is this possible in Salesforce?

I am not being able to add permission to the Guest User profile or Assign a permission set.

Comment: Per the [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_model_fields.htm&type=5), Activity's access is controlled by the record it is associated to. Do you have the necessary access on the parent record where the activity needs to be accessed?

Comment: It has read and create permission on related contact and opportunity but, it is throwing an insufficient access error when I try to edit the event via guest user @JayantDas

Comment: You are mentioning that you are trying to "edit" an event and that the profile has "read" and "create" permissions on contact and opportunity, does it have "edit" permission too?

Comment: The edit permission for Contact and Opportunity is disabled for guest user. I am not being able to set it.

Comment: And seems like there's no ability to allow "edit" permission on standard objects for guest user profiles.

Comment: Is there any work-around?

Answer (score 0):

Rolling up contents from comments with some relevant pointers.

Based on your inputs, seems like you are trying to "Edit" an Activity record on either Contact or Opportunity from a Guest User Profile.

Going through the documentation on Activity, the permissions on Activity is determined by the record to which it is associated to. Refer to the excerpt below from the [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_model_fields.htm&type=5).

[image]

Furthermore, going through some more help articles, it seems like Standard Objects cannot have "Edit" permission for a Guest User Profile and thus you cannot "Edit" any associated Activity either. Below are some excerpts from the help articles.

Excerpt from this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=siteforce_data_access_perms.htm&type=5).

> In the site’s guest user profile, enable the “Read” permission on the standard or custom objects you want to retrieve data from using data repeaters, data tables, or data functions. Enable the “Create” permission on the objects you want to submit data to using forms. All permissions that aren't set by default must be set manually.

Excerpt from this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006778&language=en_US&type=1).

> 6. These profiles are associated to guest user licenses which give the ability to read/create on standard objects and full CRUD on custom objects.  However, by default no CRUD is given.  Admins needs to enable the right level of access based on their flow

---

**As for your use case**, if at all you want to edit an event, an option I can see is to use a "custom event object" and utilize that to solve for your use case.